# Saving Relational Parse Object

Tags: parse-platform

Consider I have a parse object A and is related to object B. I want to save the object A.

So I create an instance of object B and assign it to instance of A before saving A.

Please help me, which of the following is correct:

1. I save object B first and then assign it to object A and then save object A

OR

2. I assign the object B to object A and save object A. This will save object B and A at once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take an example here. Suppose you have a **Post** object, and you have a **Comment** object. You can think of two types of relations here. You can put the comment object to the post object like the following.

```
postObject.add(commentObject); // See add() is used because there can be more than one comments to a single post (1 -> N)
```

In some implementations, creating the relation the other way is better.

```
commentObject.put("parentPost", postObject); // In this case put() is used, because a comment will have only one parent post object
```

Now regarding saving to parse. The save state of an object does not matter when adding relations. So in the first case, the complete code would look something like shown below.

```
ParseObect commentObject = new ParseObject("Comment");
commentObject.put("text", "This is a test comment");
ParseObject postObject = new ParseObject("Post");
postObject.add(commentObject);
postObject.save(); // post & comment are saved and related now
```

For the second scenario, things are like the below.

```
ParseObect commentObject = new ParseObject("Comment");
commentObject.put("text", "This is a test comment");
ParseObject postObject = new ParseObject("Post");
commentObject.put("parentPost", postObject);
commentObject.save(); // post & comment are saved and related now
```

Hope this helps.